# Explanation for open covering 0f $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $\mathscr{O}=\{(0,1-1/n):n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover for $(0,1)$. I am confused with the case $n=1$; what is the interpretation of $(0)$?

Answer (score 2):

(0,0) is the empty set; the set of all x such that 0< x < 0.

Comment: Of course, sorry!

Comment: Don't apologize!  It was a legitimate question and not immediately obvious.

Comment: So, in this case it is not an open cover for $(0,1)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Also, Shoutre, you say my $\mathscr{O}$ is not an open cover?

Comment: Sure it is.  The $\mathscr{O}_1$ is unneeded and trivial but, for all $x \in (0,1)$ then $x \in  \mathscr{O}_n = (0, 1 - 1/n) $for some $n$ (but n will not equal 1).  So, yes, it is an open cover.

Comment: @Shoutre: $\mathscr{O}_1 = (0, 0) = \emptyset$ by itself is not a cover by itself and if it is part of any open cover, it can be dismissed. But the remainder will still be an open cover.  So $\mathscr{P} = \{(0, 1/n)| n \in \mathbb N ; n \ge 2\} \subset \mathscr{O} $ is also an open cover.

Comment: You are totally right. Somehow I got stupidly confused and thought that each one of the $\mathscr{O}_{n}$ was an open cover. Sorry, obviously $\mathscr{O}$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, well, no one of them is an open cover and further more every $\mathscr{O}_i \subset \mathscr{O}_{i + 1}$ so if there were any finite subcover it would be a single one of them.  (So (0, 1) is not compact.)